# How to retrieve the deleted site collection back into the respective place in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Unfortunately a site collection has been deleted from Central administrator. How to retrieve a that site collection in Sharepoint 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the powershell command to get the list of deleted site collection using following command

```
Get-SPDeletedSite "/"
```

Once you find the deleted site collection in the list just restore that particular site collection back using following command

```
Restore-SPDeletedSite -Identity 610857cb-8414-4a89-8bf3-ad3628f6c86c
```

For more detail you can refer [Get-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316(v=office.14).aspx) and [Restore-SPDeletedSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286319(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Yes we have tried all the above command but it shows "File not found" is there any other way to retrieve deleted site collection

Comment: Then you are screwed unless you have a database backup

Comment: Yes Eric, You are rite but any how we have database backup, so we have to try from that.